# How to access QuerySet element at specific index without IndexError?

Tags: python, django

I am having trouble retrieving the second-to-last element in a queryset list in Django.

I know i can filter it like this:

```
 QuoteOfTheDay.objects.all().order_by('-id')[1]
```

but I need a safe way to do this so that when it is empty, it won't return an

> IndexError at / list index out of range

Comment: Have you tried adding a condition that checks that you have at least two elements in the returned QuerySet? What's supposed to happen if the list is empty?

Comment: How could i check if two items are inside of a query set with an if condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following, using [`count`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.count) to check how many items are inside the queryset

```
quotes = QuoteOfTheDay.objects.order_by('-id')
second_to_last = None
if quotes.count() > 1:
    second_to_last = quotes[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a `try-except` block.

```
try:

    query_set = QuotesOfTheDay.objects.all().orderby('-id')[-1]
    ** other logic here **

except IndexError:
    print('No Quotes')
```